# Можно ли авторизироваться в curl и запомнить логин и пароль для данного http?

Tags: curl, авторизация

Учусь пользоваться `curl`. Завел на `localhost` базу данных и пользуюсь ее api чтоб отправлять ей команды. В `curl` запросы постоянно приходится добавлять флаг `-u "login:password"`, что при копировании их из документации не совсем удобно, ведь запрос сразу пытается выполниться, но не может без авторизации и в консоль прилетает ошибка.

Можно ли как-то автоматически логинится через `curl`? Например, ввести команду типа

`curl -XPUT http:localhost:9200 -u "login:password" --automaticaly`
и чтобы `curl` подставлял логин и пароль при обращении к этому хосту?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем то, что я искал, но можно скачать [vs-code REST Client](https://github.com/Huachao/vscode-restclient) и делать curl запросы через него, поместив повторяющиеся части в переменную.

```
@username = elastic
@password = elasticpass
@host = http://localhost
@port_1 = 9200
@curl = curl -k -u {{username}}:{{password}} {{host}}:{{port_1}}

@index_name = first_index

### Getting index by name curl
{{curl}}/{{index_name}}/?pretty

### Delete index by name
{{curl}}/{{index_name}}/?pretty -X DELETE
```

Также можно делать и обычные REST API запросы через этот клиент.